# When you press button it uses previously pressed button id in voting system

Tags: php, html, database

I was trying to make voting system for my project in php. Issue is when im pressing `vote` button function `$_POST["submit$i"]` working for previosly pressed button and vote is writing to wrong id in db.

Here is my code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
include 'dbconn.php'; //sql db connection
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `Petitions` WHERE `Status` = 'in voting' LIMIT 50");
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$i = 1; // index of item in foreach
?>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="blank"></div>
    <?php foreach($data as $row): ?> //foreach
    <div class="petition">
        <div class="header">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($row['Title']) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($row['Text']) ?>
        </div>
        <div>
                <?php //function for button
                if (isset($_POST["submit$i"])) {
                    $iid = $row['id'];
                    $morevote = $row['Votes'] + 1;
                    $morevoted = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `Petitions` SET `Votes`= $morevote WHERE `id` = $iid LIMIT 50");
                    $morevoted = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `Petitions` SET `Votes`= $morevote WHERE `id` = $iid LIMIT 50");
                }
                ?>
            <form method="post" class="vote">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Vote"/>
                    <?= htmlspecialchars($row['Votes']) ?>/<?= htmlspecialchars($row['Needed votes']) ?>
                    </form>
        </div>
        <div class="blank1"></div>  
       </div>
       <?php $i++;?>
       <?php endforeach ?>
           <div class="blank2"></div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant use `$i` as an id in db command because it can be without `in voting` status. Thank you in advance!

*P.S. i fixed the problem by using `hidden` outside of foreach*

Comment: Those "indexed" submit button names are a bad idea to begin with. (As is _processing_ the submitted data inside of your loop, that creates the frontend output - violation of the basic [IPO model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model), that you should attempt to follow to write clean structured applications.) So instead use _static_ field names - and either add a hidden field to the form, that transports the `$row['id']` value directly, or switch from using `input type="submit"` to a `button`, and put the `$row['id']` into the value attribute of that button.

Comment: By sending the row id directly, instead of a loop index, you won't have to go through any extra trouble to correlate the two to each other any more, which means you can easily move the processing part to the start of the script.

Comment: This would be far simpler if either there was a single form (rather than potentially hundreds ) or you used ajax to send the vote to a php script

Comment: Your HTML appears to be missing a `head` section so is invalid and could cause issues all its own if you have any Javascript in use

Comment: Please be warned that your `UPDATE` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 1):

Over here:

```
$result11 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `Petitions` WHERE `Status` = 'in voting' LIMIT 50");
$datarow = $result11->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$datarow = $datarow[$i-1]; <--
$iid = $datarow['id'];
```

you should use $i instead of $i-1 because foreach increments $i in the end of the loop so you will always get the previous value inside of the loop

Also, change the $i starting value to 0 instead of 1:

```
$i = 0;
```

and in the previous file, youre missing a semicolon:

```
 $iid = $row['id']
```

Comment: sadly still the same thing but +1 at $i

Comment: try $datarow = $datarow[$i] and put $i = 0 instead of $i = 1;

Comment: still the same as at start(